# FLUTTER Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)

Tags: flutter, hive

I got this problem when I use NoSQL Hive and in the pubspec.yaml file I set upped the path_provider package.

I ran the `flutter pub get` and tried to reinstall all packages and `flutter clean` but it's still got this error.

```
 Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49  throw_
    packages/flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart 313:7                                                                  _invokeMethod
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1660:54                                          runUnary
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                    handleValue
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 767:44                                    handleValueCallback
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 796:13                                    _propagateToListeners
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 567:5                                     [_completeWithValue]
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 640:7                                     callback
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15           <fn>
```

This is my main file:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  var directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(directory.path);
  runApp(
    DevicePreview(
      enabled: !kReleaseMode,
      builder: (context) => MyApp(), // Wrap your app
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      useInheritedMediaQuery: true,
      locale: DevicePreview.locale(context),
      builder: DevicePreview.appBuilder,
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of hot-restart, try to terminate the app and re-run the application again. That should fix the issue.